# Making a Markov chain directed graph neat and orderly and symmetrical and legible

Tags: graph-theory, markov-chains, visualization

Imagine an infinite sequence of coin tosses, each yielding $h$  or $t.$

If the $n\text{th,}$ $(n+1)\text{th},$ and $(n+2)\text{th}$ tosses yield (for example) $hth,$ then the $(n+1)\text{th},$ $(n+2)\text{th},$ and $(n+3)\text{th}$ tosses may be either $thh$ or $tht.$ Thus the set of all eight sequences of length $3$ is a Markov chain whose directed graph looks like this:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccc}
& & & hht & & & \longrightarrow & & & htt \\
& & \nearrow & & \searrow & & & & \nearrow & & \searrow \\
\hookrightarrow & hhh & & \uparrow & & hth & \longleftrightarrow & tht & & \downarrow & & ttt & \hookleftarrow \\
& & \nwarrow & & \swarrow & & & & \nwarrow & &\swarrow \\
& & & thh & & & \longleftarrow & & & tth
\end{array}
$$
I've attempted to make a neat and orderly and graphically legible and pleasing version of the corresponding graph for four consecutive tosses and I can see as the number increases this may become challenging. Is this a solved problem? If so, is the solution in print somewhere? And can it be described here?

Comment: If you happen to have Mathematica v12.1 or later then here's some code to experiment with: https://pastebin.com/hPxr4kAu

Comment: Wikipedia has [some pictures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph) but only for $n=3$ or less.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/De_Bruijn_binary_graph.svg

Comment: What about: $$(X_{n-2}, X_{n-1}, X_{n}, T)\leftarrow (X_{n-3}, X_{n-2}, X_{n-1}, X_n) \rightarrow (X_{n-2}, X_{n-1}, X_n, H) $$

Comment: @Michael : What about it? $\qquad$